# Using state data Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement search in my Angular app, i fetch my query data in an array of objects . My challenge here is passing that data using state into the component that displays that data.

My approach is found on this link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3vndg1)

Use the keyword "Harry" to test search

Comment: You should have posted relevant code here at SO

Comment: It would complain of so much code, @Satpal your help would really be appreciated. thanks